# Neo4j Join Two Labels Using IN Clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two labels: CreditCardTransaction and Customer and I want to return the credit card transactions for only 5 customers.  I have a relationship defined between Customer and CreditCardTransaction that is called `MAKES`.  Here is the cypher query I tried but it didn't work.  Can someone please help with the correct cypher query? I'm still learning how to form my queries in cypher.  I've also included what the SQL would look like.

Cypher Query (doesn't work):

```
MATCH (c:Customer)
WHERE c.CustomerName IN ['AFFORDABLE PRO TRANSPORT','NDAWIND TRANSPORT LLC','CARGO CHAMP, LLC','HORVAT LOGISTICS LLC','GTS','GENERAL TRANSPORT, LLC','JITC LOGISTICS LLC','AIR GROUND & OCEAN LOGISTICS INC.']<-[:Customer]-(:CreditCardTransaction)<-[:MAKES]-(:Customer)
RETURN c;
```

SQL Query:

```
Select * from Customer c
inner join CreditCardTransaction cc on c.CustomerID = cc.CustomerID
Where c.CustomerName in ('Company ABC','XYZ Inc.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to success. Your `WHERE` clause has more than five customers in it though.

This will return the customer and the credit card transactions for all of the customers in you `WHERE` clause.

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[:MAKES]->(cc:CreditCardTransaction)
WHERE c.CustomerName IN ['AFFORDABLE PRO TRANSPORT','NDAWIND TRANSPORT LLC','CARGO CHAMP, LLC','HORVAT LOGISTICS LLC','GTS','GENERAL TRANSPORT, LLC','JITC LOGISTICS LLC','AIR GROUND & OCEAN LOGISTICS INC.']
RETURN c, cc
```